# Member access into incomplete type error

Tags: c++

I have the following files structure that contain the definition of a struct an encapsulating type, when I try to access a member of the struct, I get the `Member access into incomplete type` error. What is the problem?

*foo_encoder.c*:

```
#include "foo.h"
//...
struct FooEncoder {
  int A;
  int B;
  foo_int32 C;
  //...
}
```

*foo.h*:

```
extern "C" {
  typedef struct FooEncoder FooEncoder;
  //...
}
```

*foo_interface.h*:

```
typedef struct MyFooEncInst FooEncInst;
```

*foo_interface.cc*:

```
#include "foo_interface.h"
#include "foo.h"
//...
struct MyFooEncInst {
  FooEncoder* encoder;
};
//...
MyFoo_Encode(FooEncInst* inst,...) {
//...
  if (d > inst->encoder->C) { // This is where I get the error
//...
}
```

`foo_int32` is defined in another place.

Comment: inlcude foo_encoder.c into the code and it will work. Let me know after that and will give full answer. Another way is to do full definition of struct FooEncoder in new .h file and include it.

Comment: You are trying to access a member of a variable of type `MyFooInst*`. However, in the code you provided there is no definition of the type `MyFooInst`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're asking for a member in the `FooEncoder` struct which isn't visible anywhere in your *foo_interface.cc* file. This looks similar to a [pimpl idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer).

In order to have your code aware of `FooEncoder`'s structure you need to either

```
#include "foo_encoder.c"
```

in your *foo_interface.cc* file (I quite don't like this solution and you didn't post the full code either) or move your struct definition elsewhere in a header file and include that one (recommended).

Answer (score 3):

foo.h is declaring a type definition to a struct that is only defined in foo.c, so foo_interface.cc has no visibility as to what FooEncoder actually is. You can fix this by moving the struct definition from foo_encoder.c to foo.h.

Answer (score 1):

The type you are trying to access is only forward declared at the time you try to access it. You can have a look at this [question to learn what a forward declaration is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration) while [answers to this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration) explain when you can use a forward declaration and when you cannot.

Your typedef in *foo.h* basically act as a forward declaration for type `FooEncoder`. You include the file in *foo_interface.cc*. So the compiler knows, that the types **exist** but it does not know anything about its internals, like what members it has. Therefore it does not know if there is a member `C` like you request it to access.
You need to tell the compiler how `MyFooEncInst` and `FooEncoder` look like internally for it to be able to access any members.